# How to change the speed of an action in bge without interrupting the loop?

Tags: animation, game-engine

I have an analog controller and I want to change action speed on the runtime, but without interrupting the loop of the action. I tried this but it doesn't work. The loop restart all the time when the variable_that_changes changes.

```
armature_object.playAction("run",0,30,play_mode = bge.logic.KX_ACTION_MODE_LOOP, speed= variable_that_changes)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use skip the automatic play modes and implement an on counter.

You can do this even without python. Define a float property "frame" that is supposed to hold the frame of the pose to be played.

Whenever the property change activate an action actuator in property mode with that property.

[image]

Now you can implement logic that manipulates the property frame.

Comment: Just adding "frame" in the action property doesn't work, but adding it also in Frame Property works! Thanks. Modify your answer and I will accept it!

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot the true level triggering. Now it works! Thank you

Comment: However it seems working better using the AlwaysSensor with the  true level triggering.

Comment: Using the always sensor is inefficient - unless the property changes all the time. As this is your current situation, it should be fine.